# Ionic / Angular JS - How to parse {{value}} inside onclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this Angular JS HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Articol">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <img ng-src="{{article.image}}">
    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{article.published}}</p>
    <p ng-bind-html="article.text"></p>
    <p>
      <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(null /* msg */, null /* img */, '{{article.url}}')">Facebook</button>
      <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter(null /* msg */, null /* img */, '{{article.url}}')">Twitter</button>
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Everything is working fine but not the `{{article.url}}` inside `onclick=""`. If I put the `{{article.url}}` inside a `<p></p>` it's working fine. **How can I fix this?**

Comment: Why don't you use "ng-click" ?

Comment: Can you give me an example based on the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach could be to keep it fully clean (i.e no script in html), it can achieved as

```
<button ng-click="posttofb()">Facebook</button>
```

In controller

```
app.controller(funcion($scope){    

   $scope.posttofb = function (){    
      window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(null, null, $scope.article.url);
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote from `{{article.url}}`

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(null /* msg */, null /* img */, {{article.url}})">Facebook</button>
```

Comment: Same thing. It doesn't replace it with the URL.

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(null /* msg */, null /* img */, {{article.url}})">Facebook</button>

Comment: Yes, if I harcode the URL inside, it works perfectly.